# Navigation with images overlapping into each other

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, html-lists, overlap

I have to make a navigation with its elements overlapping into each other. See the picture for details.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7551300/mock.png

I have tried using ul li with display:table-row and display table-cell to ensure that all elements get equal widths in the div the ul is in. This is important because there will be several of these navigations with either 3 or 4 elements and I don't want to hardcode their widths each time.

I was looking for a solution with overlapping background-image properties but I failed.

How could one solve this problem? I'm stuck...

edit:
here is the jsfiddle with my code regarding

```
<li class="first-menu-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-9 current_page_item menu-item-18" id="menu-item-18">
        <a href="http://rmbp.home/wordpress/?page_id=9">Psychologie</a>
 </li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yA4zK/

Comment: Could you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index and some positioning to achieve what you are looking for.

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">uno</li>
    <li class="second">dos</li>
    <li class="third">tres</li>
    <li class="fourth">quatro</li>
</ul>
```

and css:

```
li{display:inline-block;border:1px solid red; padding: 10px;float:left; position:relative; min-width:100px}
li.first{background: green; z-index: 100; left: 0}
li.second{background:yellow; z-index: 99;left: -10px;}
li.third{background:purple; z-index: 98;left: -20px;}
li.fourth{background:brown; z-index: 97;left: -30px;}
```

You get the idea.

Take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/JKmEQ/

Here is a css only option:

```
<ul>
    <li>uno</li>
    <li>dos</li>
    <li>tres</li>
    <li>quatro</li>
</ul>



li{display:inline-block;border:1px solid red; padding: 10px;float:left; position:relative; min-width:100px}
li:first-child{background: green; z-index: 100; left: 0}
li:nth-child(2){background:yellow; z-index: 99;left: -10px;}
li:nth-child(3){background:purple; z-index: 98;left: -20px;}
li:last-child{background:brown; z-index: 97;left: -30px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TkyKj/

May not work if you care about old IE support. In that case you might need a bit of js to add clases for you.

http://caniuse.com/#search=nth

Comment: Thank you very much! But I forgot to mention that I use Wordpress and I only have li's like class="first" and class="last". So I sadly cannot write special css for each li. Is there another Way to achieve what you did?

Comment: You can use the css only option (the second example). If older browser support is required, you could shore this up with a small bit of jQuery to add the classes for you.